# Dynamically hide/transparent header in react navigation 4x?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a loader in place but in loads under the header. What i need is too hide or make the header transparent when the loader is loading and again reshow or unhide the header when the loader is ended !

How to implement that ?

As of now am using this,

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: navigation.getParam('from'),
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#673AB7',
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: '#fff'
            },
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
            headerTintColor: '#fff'
        }
    };
```

Can this be changed dynamically ? if so how is it ? please guide !

Am using react navigation 4x

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
const loading = <Some state to be received as a prop whether the loader is loading>

stackName: {
  screen:ComponentScreenName,
  navigationOptions: {
    headerShown: !loading
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a static [navigationOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-options-resolution/) you can use for screens prior to version 5.

you can update these [props](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator#navigationoptions-for-screens-inside-of-the-navigator) based on state

```
static navigationOptions = {
  headerShown: !isLoading,
};
```

after react-navigation v5 you use [setOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions) for same functionality.